# JQuery Maintain multiple drag and drop state to keep color of the item with the state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an Accordion and two droppable areas where user is allowed to drop items. I want color of the dropped item inside an accordion to be changed to red. You can check my [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/montel388/ow29t4t7/9/).

What I use to change color of the item inside accordion:

```
sourceElement.css('color','#e62e00');
```

And then when remove the item form droppable area change color back to black:

```
$(".projLeader").on('click', '.closer', function(){
            var item = $(this).closest('.dropClass');

            var element = $("#myAccordion ul li").filter(function() {
                    return $(this).text() == item.text(); 
            });
            //$(this).droppable("enable");
            itm.splice(item);
            element.css('color','black');
            item.fadeTo(200, 0, function(){ item.remove(); })
});
```

What I want is if for example I dropped same item in two different droppable areas and then remove one color should be still red, until i remove item from another area. How it can be achieve?

Comment: You can have a look at the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your `fiddle` to handle this.

https://jsfiddle.net/ow29t4t7/12/

What I have done is, added a `data` attribute as below with the drop count

```
var dropCount = sourceElement.data('dropCount');
sourceElement.data('dropCount', dropCount ? parseInt(dropCount) + 1 : 1);
```

And checking the same as below when it removed and changing the `color` if it is `zero` to make sure this does not exist in other dropped boxes.

```
var dropCount = element.data('dropCount');
dropCount = dropCount && dropCount > 0 ? parseInt(dropCount) - 1 : 0;
element.data('dropCount', dropCount);
if(dropCount === 0) {
  element.css('color','black');
}
```